Flutter Supabase Auth by Google error in not localhost version
I have a problem: when i try to auth with Google using Supabase on localhost (WEB) - this work correctly: after authentication in my URL i can see ?code=?code=7c... . But when i try to auth using Google from real link (in my case - Firebase Hosting generated domain) - auth don't finalize corryctly, and i see /auth/v1/authorize?provider=google&flow_type=pkce&code_challenge=3Y... in URL. So, Supabase.instance.client.auth.currentUser returns null.
In Redirect URL's in Supabase console 100% exist correctly redirect URL - i checked this more than 10 times.
How i can fix it?
In Redirect URL's in Supabase console 100% exist correctly redirect URL - i checked this more than 10 times.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth(         OAuthProvider.google,         authScreenLaunchMode: kIsWeb ? LaunchMode.platformDefault : LaunchMode.externalApplication,         redirectTo: 'https://app.carplayconnect.io/',       );
This is calling on SupabaseAuth using Google. Site URL was defined in SupabaseDevConsole.
On the bottom i povide method, that check current user session, but after login using method from the top of this message returns null:
 final User? response = supabase.auth.currentUser;
Mayebe can i provider some another information?
